# LeftbarButtonItem remove padding?

Tags: swift

I would like to use a logo as LeftbarButtonItem in an UINavigationController, is it possible to remove the left padding here?

Ill alreay tried:

```
    let logoView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(-15, 0, 44, 44))
    logoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    var leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftBarButtonItem, animated: false)
```

But thats not working. Ill mean that space shown here in this picture:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is the Swift Solution:

```
    let logoView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44))
    logoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -20;

    let leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoView)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, leftBarButtonItem]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of removing the padding to the left of a custom left button item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem // Assume this exists, filled with our custom view

// Create a negative spacer to go to the left of our custom back button, 
// and pull it right to the edge:
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace 
    target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -5; 

// Note: We use 5 above b/c that's how many pixels of padding iOS seems to add

// Add the two buttons together on the left:
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray 
    arrayWithObjects:negativeSpacer, backButtonItem, nil];
```

Comment: Ill still found that (old) solution, but its not working anymore.

Comment: Ok, now it works - thanks. Ill add the Swift solution.

Comment: The only thing that has worked for me so far. Thanks!

Comment: @erkanyildiz :  Did you found a way to make it work in iOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

swift version of @Piyush Sharma ' Answer

```
actionBarWidth = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width as! CGFloat
actionBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height as! CGFloat

actionBarView.frame = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: actionBarWidth, height: actionBarHeight)

 let emptySpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
 emptySpace.width = -16
 let leftBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: actionBarView)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [emptySpace,leftBarBtn]
```

Comment: Where does the magic -16 come from? This value may be different based on device size.

Comment: @user246392 ı have tested specific devices